# StreamReader problems of some kind

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am having a problem in c# with the StreamReader object. I pass in a StreamReader object to a function, then I read through it to gather some information about its contents. Once I pass it through the code to gather information I think its empty when I pass it to subsequent functions.

```
public DataScraper GetDataValues(StreamReader sr)
{

    DataScraper dsGd = new DataScraper();

    string line = string.Empty;
    int intCurrentLine = 0;
    int intLineAskingPrice = 0;
    int intLineHOADues = 0;
    int intLineTaxes = 0;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("For Sale: $"))
            intLineAskingPrice = intCurrentLine;
        if (line.Contains(@"<span>HOA Fee</span>"))
            intLineHOADues = intCurrentLine - 1;
        if (line.Contains("<em>Annually:</em>"))
            intLineTaxes = intCurrentLine + 1;
        intCurrentLine++;
    }

    //<span>HOA Fee</span>
    dsGd.intAskingPrice = GetAskingPrice(sr, intLineAskingPrice);
    dsGd.intHOADues = GetHOADues(sr, intLineHOADues);
    dsGd.intTaxes = GetTaxes(sr, intLineTaxes);

    return dsGd;
}
```

Any thoughts how I can pass in a StreamReader object through subsequent functions and be at the beginning of the StreamReader instead of the end (if that is what is actually happening to my code)?

Comment: does your intline stuff have values??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You read everything from stream in this while loop and then you want to read everything a second time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `Position` of the `BaseStream` to `0`, this works only if your `underlying stream` supports `Position`. I hope that's not your case.

```
public DataScraper GetDataValues(StreamReader sr)
{
  if(sr.BaseStream != null&&sr.BaseStream.CanSeek) sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
  //remaining code
  //....
  //....
}
```

Comment: Note that this works only if the underlying stream supports positioning. It wouldn't work if the `StreamReader` is connected to a `NetworkStream`, for example.

Comment: @JimMischel thank you, that's helpful. It looks like that it's not the case of the OP, I'm going to add note about that in my answer. If it's the case the OP can't `rewind` his underlying stream, can he?

Comment: If `BaseStream` does not support positioning, then there's no way to rewind it. With a `NetworkStream`, for example, once you read the data, it's gone. If that's the case, he'll want to read it into a `MemoryStream` first, and then attach the `StreamReader` to that.